# Django not authenticating using custom User model

Tags: python, django

I am trying to authenticate users against an existing database. I can authenticate the user with their email and password combination but I cannot save the authorisation, meaning the user is not actually logged in.

I know this because in Template.html, it is not showing the correct options after login when I call `{% if user and not user.is_anonymous %}`

I believe the fault is coming from this line in `views.py`

```
auth_login(request, user)
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout as auth_logout
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

...

def login_email(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = hashlib.md5(request.POST.get('password')).hexdigest()

        #db query to check if email and password combination exist
        user = Users.objects.get(email=email,password=password)

        if user is not None:
            user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'  
            auth_login(request, user)
            return redirect('/personalised')
        else: #failed to return to login page
            return render(request, 'login.html',{})
    #invalid POST request recieved
    else:
        return render(request,"login.html",{})
```

**login.html**

```
           <form action="/login_email/" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

**Models.py**

```
class Users(models.Model):
    visitorid = models.CharField(db_column='visitorID', max_length=80)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    visits = models.IntegerField()
    last_visit = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    unsubscribe = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.TextField()
    .....
```

**template.py**

```
    {% if user and not user.is_anonymous %}
    <li><a href="/personalised">My Feed </a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Trending</a></li>
    <li><a href="/recommendations/{{user.username}}">Your Saves</a></li>
    <li><a href="/logout">Logout </a></li>
    {% else %}
    <a href="/login_email?next={{ request.path }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn">Sign in with Email</button></a>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use this code:

```
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password = hashlib.md5(request.POST.get('password')).hexdigest()

    #db query to check if email and password combination exist
    user = Users.objects.get(email=email,password=password)
```

Instead use [the `authenticate` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate). It returns a `User`

```
user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
```

This assumes that you have an appropriate [auth backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) setup.